# Java inexplicably writes to file with good or wrong codepage depending on web API call URL

Tags: java, windows, character-encoding

Good evening,

I am thoroughly baffled by a behaviour that happens with a Java application of mine.

The application is to be used to connect to a web API and download a table of data from there to be further used in academic research.

I was trying to set the export to correct encoding, to save time, I disabled iteration in calls to web API by disabling some methods and removing a variable from a URL string construction - placing an integer 42 in its place.
Upon this, I was surprised to see the correct encoding.

A bit down the road, and I can confirm - if I use this URL:

```
new URL("http://www.foo.bar/api/unit?id="+scraper.ujList[i]);
```

where `ujList[]` is an array of integers,
then the output has typical wrong encoded characters like this `ÄŤasĹĄ RuĹľinov`

meanwhile, if I use

```
new URL("http://www.foo.bar/api/unit?id="+42);
```

then the output is proper, like `Ružinov`.

I have also tried Integer.toString() as well as String.valueOf() on ujList member, but it didn't help.
FWIW it does not matter if I run a jar file, a class file, or from within Eclipse.

I have no idea how to continue.

Comment: Tricky to diagnose without code/data source so that we can reproduce the problem. It might help to compare the data you download (the raw bytes, not as a String) to see whether the difference occurs during download, or during encoding into a file.

Comment: @DNA I know, though first I'd need to clean it up. Quick and dirty, not much code reuse, so almost everything is in main loop.. I'll try to do this tomorrow.

Anyway the data seems same as far into it as I can get in the debug window. That was also one of my first ideas when looking at the wrong encoding.

Comment: What Content-Type is the web site returning? It sounds like the site is actually returning data in a different encoding when you change the parameter in the URL.

Comment: @DNA I have to retract the last statement. Data was OK when I originally looked at them, do not seem OK now.
**But.** They both look wrong in exactly the same way in both occurences. I have played with project default encoding settings between looking at this, which explains the difference in debug.

Comment: @DavidConrad It's application/json with UTF-8 encoding. There is no difference in the actual URL - indeed the data flows the same way as I traverse the code in debug mode.

Comment: Are you wrapping the input stream in a reader, and if so, what encoding are you specifying for the reader?

Comment: @DavidConrad InputStreamReader wrapped in a Buffered Reader, no charset specified (will try)

Comment: Well, I try to never rely on the default encoding, and instead specify the encoding. My philosophy is, always assume the default encoding is going to be something insane, like EBCDIC.

Comment: @DavidConrad That seems to have helped (at least at a first glance) - and I can agree with not depending on default encoding - but the question still remains - what the hell was it doing (when it wasn't working)? I have this nagging feeling Java is going to be a bit like Airbus _(there is this joke among airline pilots - How do you tell a rookie Airbus pilot from an experienced one? Rookie says: "What is it doing?". Experienced says: "Hey, it's doing it again!")_